# How/where to cite corrigendum publication on CV?

Tags: publications, citations, cv, citation-style, errors-erratum

Citations for my publications on my CV are listed in reverse chronological order, and I am wondering how/where to list the citation for a corrigendum.

Should I list the corrigendum and original article citations one after the other (even if the list would then not be strictly reverse-chronological because there are other publications in between)? Should I make a note about the corrigendum in/after the citation of the original publication (or maybe a footnote)? Should I list it all reverse-chronologically even if the corrigendum citation is then not listed close to the citation of the original article?

Comment: Personally, I would add the correction to the citation for the original article, since they really go together. I certainly would not claim it as a separate publication.

Comment: @JonCuster What if you published a corrigendum for someone else's paper?

Comment: I’ve never seen someone publish a corrigendum on someone else’s article. Those are Comments if you point out an issue. But I could well be surprised…

Answer (score 2):

I would list them together, with the add-on content either a) in brackets, or b) indented with a tab to clearly mark them as part of the same work. You really don't want it to appear like you're trying to make your citation list longer by having published corrigenda.

Here's an example of how option (a) might look:

---

Rogers, M. E., Craig, A. C., Munns, R. E., Colmer, T. D., Nichols, P. G. H., Malcolm, C. V., ... & Evans, P. M. (2005). The potential for developing fodder plants for the salt-affected areas of southern and eastern Australia: an overview. [Corrigendum: 2006, v. 46, no. 12, p. 1665.].

---

Note here that really all you need for this paper is the latter details to find the best current version of the paper as the journal has stitched them together at least for the online version. You might opt to keep both details if the journal hasn't done that, though the corrigendum will at minimum include a citation to the full paper.

I think it's up to you whether you'd list this paper with other 2005 papers or 2006; I'd probably keep it with 2005, the original publication date.

Comment: Hi Bryan, what if I published a corrigendum for someone else's paper?

Comment: @HighGPA I don't know, I haven't heard of such a thing.